# use a specific overload without a cast?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I'd like to create some helper methods that are inheritance aware.  I'd like them to work like virtual + override methods, yet without having to define a class hierarchy.

Here's how it might work with a cast.  I'd like to be able to do this without the performance his of having multiple casts... and without defining yet another hierarchy:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args){
        var a = new A();
        var b = new B();

        var h = new Helper();
        h.DoSomething(a);
        h.DoSomething(b);
    }
}

public class A{}

public class B : A{}

public class Helper{
    public void DoSomething(A o){}

    public void DoSomething(B o){
        DoSomething((A)o);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no performance penalty in having a cast from `B` to `A` - it's guaranteed to be correct, so there's no actual check to be performed. It's just delegating the method call.

Having said that, I'd actually recommend against using overloads with type hierarchies like this. [Overloading can get pretty complicated...](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)

(And as ever, don't *assume* a performance penalty without testing. Create a clean design, and test the performance. Only start bending things out of shape when you've *found* a problem.)

Comment: +1 thank again Jon.  You are right, I shouldn't have assumed.  For this need I've seen XML or Attributes + Reflection used.  However, sometimes things are too configurable.  Trying to keep the existing heirarchy as clean as possible.  This is an attempt at a sensible compromise.

Answer (score 2):

If `B` inherits from `A` then callers can simply provide an instance of `B` directly to:

```
public void DoSomething(A o){}
DoSomething(new B());
```

So there is no need for the other method.  And to remove the ambiguity, the cast might be required, otherwise the compiler cannot determine what method you wish to call - as both are valid for the provided arguments.

Casts and performance should only be a concern if you can prove that the casting is causing problems.  Trying to pre-empt things like this might just end up being premature optimisation.

That said, I have witnessed slow code paths of things that comprise of deep hierarchies (lots of overridden methods).

Comment: +1 @Adam Houldsworth thanks for the just go with it 'premature optimisation' comment.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you cast? As far as `B : A` you can pass your `B` into method accepting `A`:

```
public void DoSomething(A o) { }

DoSomething(new A());
DoSomething(new B());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare both variables as of `dynamic` type (new `.NET 4.0 Framework` type - [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)) or simply cast to dynamic. 
Take a look how `dynamic` allows resolve type in runtime and choose an appropriate overload method:

```
dynamic a = new A();
dynamic b = new B();
var h = new Helper();         

h.DoSomething(a); // will be called DoSomething(A o)        
h.DoSomething(b); // will be called DoSomething(B o)
```